# How to log bandwidth usage for Apache virtual hosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, bandwidth

I need a way to extract bandwidth usage logs for Apache virtual hosts. I see that a lot of people are recommending AWStats (and similar programs), but I don't need a graphical interface. All I need is usage data formatted in way that can be accessed by our billing program.

Something like this would be **glorious**:

```
<usage host="foo.com">
    <usage year="2009" month="2" bytes_in="12345" bytes_out="1235678" />
    ...
</usage>
```

It doesn't have to be xml, as long as it's fairly easy to parse and extract the vital information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using apache 2+ you can use [modlogio's](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_logio.html) and %I or %O in [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) directive

config will be something like this:

LogFormat "%v %t %I %O" billing
customLog /var/log/billing.log billing

then you can use awk or perl or whatever to aggregate the data in billing log and generate the reports

Answer (score 3):

I've used the [mod_cband](http://codee.pl/cband.html) for that in the past. Its primary goal is to limit the bandwidth per vhost, but it can also log and graph them easily.